# update database sum monthly based on signup date

Tags: php, sql, database

Need help writing a function for database.  I want to keep track of the total cost of member orders each month based on their signup date.  So if someone signed up in the middle of the month, the function should add 30 days to their signup date and sum the sales whithin that period and place in database.  Then display on user page.  Using mysql functions (not PDO or mysqli for now).

Something like:

```
<?php
     $query = ("SELECT SUM(cost) FROM memberOrders WHERE 
              memberNumber='$memberNumber' GROUP BY signupdate+30days");
?>
```

But it can't be just 30 days...it should be +30, +60, +90...That's the part I'm stuck on.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your table please, it is sort of the least info you could provide ;)

Answer (score 0):

calculate the start/end date in PHP and make use of a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(cost) FROM 
      (Select cost, membernumber from memberOrders WHERE 
      memberNumber='$memberNumber' and date >= '$startdate' and date <= '$enddate' 
      GROUP BY substr(date, 7))
GRoup by membernumber
```

Comment: Can you please explain the function?  From what I understand, you want me to specify the start and end date.  The start is the date someone registers...the end date is...infinity.  That's the problem I had because there is no end date...i just want the database to add a month and check from there

Comment: In the case you want to run the query indefinitely, the above query will not work. My suggestion is to rethink the database model to suite your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have both the signup date and order date in `MemberOrders`, the following will return all months with orders:

```
SELECT datediff(orderdate, signupdate, interval month) as MonthsAfter,
       SUM(cost) as MonthCost
FROM memberOrders
WHERE memberNumber='$memberNumber'
GROUP BY datediff(orderdate, signupdate, interval month)
```

If you have all months having 30-days, you can do:

```
SELECT floor(datediff(orderdate, signupdate, interval day)/30) as Months,
       SUM(cost) as MonthCost
FROM memberOrders
WHERE memberNumber='$memberNumber'
GROUP BY floor(datediff(orderdate, signupdate, interval day)/30)
```

Note:  both of these assign "0" to the first month after signup.  Add `+1` if you want to start at 1.